# Code to missing values if all Items of an Item battery have value 1

Tags: stata

I have a large data set in Stata.

There are several item batteries in this data set.

One item battery consists of 8 items (`v1 - v8`), each scaled from 1 to 7.

I want to code all items that take the value `1` in all items as missing values.

If `v1` to `v8` have the value "1", all rows to which this applies are to be replaced with missings.

I know how to code missing values with the `if` qualifier, but the selection with the complex condition causes me difficulties.

The code for R would probably solve this via `rowSums`, but I need the solution for Stata.

(I assume in R it would work like this:

```
df[rowSums(df[,c("v1", ... "v8")]!=1)==0, c("v1", .... "v8")] <- NA
```

But I need a solution for Stata.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood this correctly, you want

```
egen rowall = concat(v1-v8) 

mvdecode v1-v8 if rowall == 8 * "1", mv(1)
```

That is, all instances in `v1-v8` of 1 are recoded as missing if and only if the values of those variables are all 1 in any observation.